# Crop image from the left side when scaling window size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Current situation:** I'm using bootstrap and I have 2 columns next to each other. When I scale the browser window, the image scales with it.

[Section on a large display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g81nl.png)

[Section on a smaller screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZieC6.png)

**The problem:**  The image that I'm working on is responsively scaling when I scale my browser window.

**What I want:**  Make sure that the image stays full height with the div and crop from the left side.

Comment: Try using `object-fit: cover;` in your `img` tag

Answer (score 0):

At its its simplest you can display the image as a background and use the various properties to make sure it stays anchored to the right, with full height and therefore gets cropped from the left as the window decreases in size.

```css
.image {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SepTG.png);
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: right center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="image"></div>
```

Note: for more modern browsers you could consider an img element and object-fit instead, but this does not work on Internet Explorer.

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have tried to make it as a background image, but sadly that does not work. It's a Shopify template and I am limited on what I can change in the html.

Comment: Hi, you need to post the minimum HTML to show the situation then. Did you you try object-fit instead as I suggested in the answer?